# Pick Active Date in a Web Page with Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, datepicker

I am trying to get the data from this web page  https://rapor.epias.com.tr/rapor/xhtml/ptfSmfListeleme.xhtml
As you can see I need to pick a beginning and end date and get the data. But the problem is when u open the calendar you can see the non-active days too especially at the final date.

I write a code for the beginning date and it is worked well but it is not practical.

```
import re
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
url = r'https://rapor.epias.com.tr/rapor/xhtml/ptfSmfListeleme.xhtml'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'...\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PmumBI:baslangicTarih"]/button/span[1]')
link.click()
while True:
    try:
        input_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-datepicker-div"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a')
        input_date.click()
    except:
        try:
            input_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-datepicker-div"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a')
            input_date.click()
        except:
            try:
                input_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-datepicker-div"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/a')
                input_date.click()
            except:
                try:
                    input_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-datepicker-div"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/a')
                    input_date.click()
                except:
                    try:
                        input_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-datepicker-div"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/a')
                        input_date.click()
                    except:
                        try:
                            input_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-datepicker-div"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]/a')
                            input_date.click()
                        except:
                            try:
                                input_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-datepicker-div"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[7]/a')
                                input_date.click()
                            except:
                                break
```

But I if I want to use the same for the final date I have to create more then 7 try code. Is there any way to make this simple, Like choosing between the active dates?

Comment: Could you give an example for a startDate and an endDate which are inactive? As I click through the calendar they all seem selectable?
Also, do you have a range of date you need to go through or do you just need random data from the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of :

```
while True:
```

You can use a **for loop and use the index** inside your xpath expression :

```
for i in range(20):
    try:
        input_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-datepicker-div"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[' +str(i)+']/a')
        input_date.click()
        break
    except:
        pass
```

Hope it'll help !

Comment: Yes it is, thanks a lot somehow I couldn't think [' +str(i)+'] like this